# Kubernetes OpenStack integration - /cluster/openstack missing?

Tags: openstack, kubernetes

Kubernetes supports OpenStack as cloudprovider (/pkg/cloudprovider/providers/openstack).

However, it seems there is no equivalent support for a OpenStack-provider to setup a cluster on an on-prem OpenStack environment via "./cluster/kube-up.sh" (supposed to be located in cluster/$IAAS_NAME).

Is my understanding correct?

If so, would there be any impediments to create such a provider as contribution? (assuming to fulfil the [requirements](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/devel/writing-a-getting-started-guide.md) for such provider)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure the kubernetes project would welcome such a contribution.

The main impediments are dealing with the fact that on-prem setups are more varied than cloud-provider-based setups, and with testing of the code you contribute.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yep, very understandable.

Comment: We're going to think about a general openstack-provider, in case we cannot come-up with a good solution, we might contribute it as "Versioned Distro"